# Magento 2 : Export is not working

Tags: magento2, admin, export

My product is fronted name is **Minerva LumaTech™ V-Tee-XS-Blue**
and backend side product name:-

[image]

but when i export product using my custom extension and open xml file i have getting error,
**error message :-**

[image]

Comment: Seems like it's html econding issue, i see that you've got some HTML going on, try html_entity_decode($field) for the field after the closure value